# Using elemMatch in Hive with json field

Tags: sql, json, hive

I am using Hive for `json` storage. Then, I have created a table with only one string column containing all the `json`. I have tested the `get_json_object` function that Hive offers but I am not able to create a query that iterates all the subdocuments in a list and finds a value in a specific field.

In MongoDB, this problem can be solved by using `$elemMatch` as [the documentation says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Is there any way to do something like this in Hive?